# lost right as administator

Tags: permissions, policykit

I have 12.04 freshly installed in my laptop. Recently I lost my rights as administrator. Hereare the problems:

1. unable to do updates from Update Manager (though no problem if I do it from terminal).
2. unable to shutdown/restart. When I press those buttons, I will only make the system logout. (no problem reboot/shutdown from terminal, though).
3. unable to store data into my FAT32 partitions. It says `Permission denied`.

It seems I lost my administrator privileges from GUI menu.

How to solve this ?

Please help me.

Comment: from a teriminal run the following commands `lsb_release -a; id` and include the results in your question.

Comment: lsb_release -a; id
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release: 12.04
Codename: precise
uid=1000(gusanto) gid=1000(gusanto) groups=1000(gusanto),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),109(lpadmin),124(sambashare)

Answer (score 0):

If you do still have the password for sudo.

Try *sudo*

If it do not work, run

```
chmod +777 <filename>
```